# Find $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos (x)\cdot\cos(3x)}{\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)\cdot \ln\left(1-x\right)}\right)$

Tags: limits

> Find $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos (x)\cdot\cos(3x)}{\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)\cdot \ln\left(1-x\right)}\right)$.

I attempted to use Taylor's theorem to find the limit, but I was not successful. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Using Taylor's approximation is fine here. Show your work otherwise it is hard to tell you what went wrong in your approach

Comment: $$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x\cdot \cos 3x}{\left( e^x-e^{-x} \right) \cdot \ln \left( 1-x \right)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left( 1-\cos x\cdot \cos 3x \right) \cdot e^x}{\left( e^{2x}-1 \right) \left( -x \right)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is $1-(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2))(1-\frac{9x^2}{2}+o(x^2))=\frac{10x^2}{2}+o(x^2)=5x^2+0(x^2)$
while the denominator is $(2x+0(x))(-x+0(x))=-2x^2+0(x^2).$
So the limit is $\frac{5}{-2}=-2.5$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.There is my sollution.
$$
\,\,\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x\cdot \cos 3x}{\left( e^x-e^{-x} \right) \cdot \ln \left( 1-x \right)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left( 1-\cos x\cdot \cos 3x \right) \cdot e^x}{\left( e^{2x}-1 \right) \left( -x \right)}
$$
$$
x\rightarrow 0,e^x-1\rightarrow x,e^{2x}-1\rightarrow 2x\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos 3x\cdot \cos x}{-2x^2}
$$
$$
Using\ Taylor'sapproximation:\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\left[ 1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+O\left( x^2 \right) \right] \cdot \left[ 1-\frac{1}{2}\left( 3x \right) ^2+O\left( x^2 \right) \right]}{-2x^2}
$$
$$
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\left( 1-5x^2 \right)}{-2x^2}=-\frac{5}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using $2\cos x \cos 3x = \cos(2x) + \cos(4x)$ which implies

$$1 - \cos x \cos 3x = \frac{1}{2}\Bigr((1-\cos 2x) + (1-\cos 4x)\Bigr) = \sin^2 x + \sin^22x$$

we can rewrite the limmand as

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x \cos 3x}{(e^x-e^{-x})\log(1-x)} = \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}+\frac{\sin^22x}{x^2}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{x}{\log(1-x)}\right)\cdot\frac{e^x}{2}$$

These are all known limits you can prove via squeeze theorem. And the limit of a product is the product of the limits when they all exist. Thus the answer without  using series or L'Hopital is

$$= \left(\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2+4\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}\right)^2\right)\cdot \left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1}{2x}\right)^{-1}\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\right)^{-1}\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x}{2}\right)$$

$$= (1+4)\cdot1\cdot-1\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \boxed{-\frac{5}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, but a way to start off.

Look at numerator and denominator for a while and then decide that the denominator is easier, because it's a product of two “degree one” term, namely
\begin{gather}
e^x-e^{-x}=2\sinh x=2x+o(x) \\[6px]
\log(1-x)=-x+o(x)
\end{gather}
Hence the denominator is
$$
-2x^2+o(x^2)
$$
so you know you can stop at degree $2$ in the numerator. Now use
$$
\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)
\qquad
\cos3x=1-\frac{(3x)^2}{2}+o(x^2)
$$
and in the product $\cos x\cos3x$ you can discard all term of degree $>2$.